# Dynamic registration of websocket output adapter is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-websocket

I am trying to implement dynamic registration of ServerWebSocketContainer so that i can publish messages to different websocket endpoints at runtime.

Here is server side code

```
@Service
public class WebSocketPublisherService {

    @Autowired
    IntegrationFlowContext integrationFlowContext;

    @Bean
    public HandshakeHandler handshakeHandler() {
        return new DefaultHandshakeHandler();
    }

    @Autowired
    RegularPublisher regularPublisher;

    public void startPublishing(String name) {
        ServerWebSocketContainer serverWebSocketContainer = new ServerWebSocketContainer(name)
                .setHandshakeHandler(handshakeHandler());

        MethodInvokingMessageSource methodInvokingMessageSource = new MethodInvokingMessageSource();
        methodInvokingMessageSource.setObject(regularPublisher);
        methodInvokingMessageSource.setMethodName("publishEmergency");

        WebSocketOutboundMessageHandler webSocketOutboundMessageHandler = new WebSocketOutboundMessageHandler(serverWebSocketContainer);
        webSocketOutboundMessageHandler.afterPropertiesSet();

        StandardIntegrationFlow standardIntegrationFlow = IntegrationFlows.from(methodInvokingMessageSource, polling -> polling.poller(pollerFactory -> pollerFactory.fixedRate(10000)))
                .split(new CustomMesssageSplitter(serverWebSocketContainer))
                .handle(webSocketOutboundMessageHandler)
                .get();

        integrationFlowContext.registration(standardIntegrationFlow)
                .addBean(serverWebSocketContainer)
                .register();

        standardIntegrationFlow.start();

    }
}


@Component
public class RegularPublisher {

    public String publishEmergency() {
        System.out.println("publishing message");
        return "This is Message from Presidenet!";
    }
}
```

And here is my client code. I am using okhttp 3.5.0 from com.squareup.okhttp3 groupId

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
StringListner listener = new StringListner();
WebSocket ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);

// Trigger shutdown of the dispatcher's executor so this process can
// exit cleanly.
client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
```

And here is listner code

```
public class StringListner extends WebSocketListener {

    private static final int NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;

    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
        System.out.println("Connection opened");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
        System.out.println("Receiving: " + text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, ByteString bytes) {
        System.out.println("Receiving: " + bytes.hex());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason) {
        webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null);
        System.out.println("Closing: " + code + " " + reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Dynamic registered topic is :  /examples

Client side passed URL:   ws://localhost:8080/examples

I am getting this error while connecting from client to websocket.

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Expected HTTP 101 response but was '404 '
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket.checkResponse(RealWebSocket.java:215)
    at okhttp3.internal.ws.RealWebSocket$2.onResponse(RealWebSocket.java:182)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime server socket endpoints registration is available only starting with Spring Integration `5.5` version: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/whats-new.html#x5.5-websocket.

The test-case on the matter looks like: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/spring-integration-websocket/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/websocket/dsl/WebSocketDslTests.java#L66

**UPDATE**

There is indeed a problem in the framework, when we have not only plain Spring Integration, but whole Spring Boot. I'm going to fix it somehow on my side, but for now here is a workaround:

1. Use only a `@SpringBootApplication`. It brings for us `@EnableIntegration`.
2. Don't use `@EnableWebSocket` since that one is going to override whatever Spring Integration would like to do. In other words `@EnableWebSocket` is not compatible with Spring Integration Websocket support. (Or wise versa)
3. You must this bean into your application context:

   ```
    @Bean
    public static BeanPostProcessor integrationDynamicWebSocketHandlerMappingWorkaround() {
        return new BeanPostProcessor() {

            @Override public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                if (bean.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("IntegrationDynamicWebSocketHandlerMapping")) {
                    ((AbstractHandlerMapping) bean).setOrder(0);
                }
                return bean;
            }
        };
    }
   ```

The problem is that `IntegrationDynamicWebSocketHandler` comes with a default `order` and it is added already after default Spring Boot's `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` which fails fast when no mapping for requested URL.

Comment: I am already using 5.5 version. I have also followed git url that you mentioned. My usecase is, i want to dynamically register websockets endpoints on server side  and once registered, it will start publishing data on it. Client will only subscribe to those endpoints and consume data. Can this be achieved by this dynamic registration change done in version 5.5? Code that i posted does that but it seems, websockets are not getting registered at runtime. Am i missing something?

Comment: Must work. I don’t see anything what would prevent. Any chances to share with us a simple project to reproduce?

Comment: Sure, I have added sample code to git. Here is link. https://github.com/pinkeshsagar-harptec/code-sample.git

Comment: Thank you for a great sample to play with! Please, find an `UPDATE` in my answer and I'll go to fix it on the framework side. This or other way...

Comment: The fix is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/3580

Comment: That fix worked. Thank you. However, there is another issue. Now if i register websocket dynamically during PostConstruct, it is initialized but from client side, i have to append /websocket at the end of url to connect to dynamically initialized websocket server. I have made changes to the code in same repo in WebSocketPublisherService class.